# Java based Thread Pool: How to test performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have written a thread pool system in JAVA that dynamically grows and shrinks based on request frequency(request per second). each request is a Runnable object that sleeps for random time interval to simulate a disk I/O. I need to compare my thread pool performance with Java's ThreadPoolExecutor. Kindly help me in following points.

1. Is there any simulation tool/benchmark tool available to test these thread pools.
2. If not then how i will test the performance of my thread pool with Java's ThreadPoolExecutor?
3. Can i use Jmeter in this scenario?
4. Can i embed my thread pool inside Tomcat to compare its performance with Tomcat's ExecutorService?

Comment: Are you sure you're capable of even writing a thread pool, when you have so many questions?

Comment: Can you explain why -1 is voted again this question? Is this question not valid?

Comment: It's not a very good question. You have 4 questions, you've somehow managed to write a threadpool, but have no idea how to test it... asking for recommendations on tools... plenty of those are basis for closing.

Comment: Take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see what constitutes a good question.

Comment: ThanX god that people like Dmitri T are at stackoverflow

Comment: Too bad there are far more people like you than people like him on here. We would be able to concentrate on real problems, not ones that result from the asker being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile your code as a .jar and add it to JMeter's classpath.

Then you can use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to call your methods and compare them with ThreadPoolExecutor using [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), for instance [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)

While developing your code make sure you:

- use "groovy" as a language (you'll need groovy-all.jar in classpath as well)
- set "Compilation Key" for something unique for each sampler

You can also consider calling your code from [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) Sampler, but it will be harder to debug and make changes as you'll have to recompile it each time while with JSR223 and groovy you'll be able  See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for more details.